# SOLR Sorting Issue in Magento

Tags: magento, sorting, solr

I have created 3 attributes: `popularity`, `reviews_count` and `pm_flat_volume`.

Those 3 attributes are containing numeric values (int).
I have defined in Solr's `schema.xml` the following dynamic fields:

```
<dynamicField name="attr_sort_reviews_count_*" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="attr_sort_pm_flat_volume_*" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="attr_sort_popularity_*" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

After refreshing the fields in the "Index Management" the following results are encountered:

- reviews_count = sorting by desc/asc : working properly
- popularity = sorting by desc/asc : working properly
- pm_flat_volume = sorting by desc/asc : not working properly (*)

(*) If I have [1, 54, 2, 3, 91, 87, 100]

```
ASC = [1, 100, 2, 3, 54, 87, 91] it should be [1, 2, 3, 54, 87, 91, 100]
DESC = [91, 87, 54, 3, 2, 100, 1] it should be [100, 91, 87, 54, 3, 2, 1]
```

I have tried different ways but none of them worked. I repeat, all those 3 attributes are having the same configuration.

Thank you!

Comment: could you try to make `pm_flat_value` of type of regular `int` and reindex?

Comment: Strange, `sint` should be sort correctly: http://markmail.org/message/ib4gevqevjilqz7n. Try open your schema.xml from Solr admin and see what type you fields have.

Comment: @archer: Is not sorting properly, neither for sint or int

Comment: @Zyava: I know. Is extremely odd. As said, the other 2 attributes are having the same configuration as the one that does not work as expected. The "schema.xml" looks OK.

Comment: SOLR 3.6.1 (if this helps) and Magento EE 1.12.x.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `class` property on the `<fieldType>` entry in your schema.xml to for both the `sint` and `int` fieldTypes. Please ensure that they are using `solr.TrieIntField`. I am suspecting that it is using `solr.IntField` which uses lexicographic ordering not numeric ordering.

Comment: Also make sure you re-index completely, if at all you have made any changes in the schema file.